# How to remove sudo permission of reboot command in sudoers file

Tags: sudo

```
# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
gauri  ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot, /sbin/shutdown
```

Comment: Possible  duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85663/poweroff-or-reboot-as-normal-user

Comment: @dennyjohn: I didn't know we allowed cross-site duplicate flags? Also that isn't their problem. They already have the line `gauri  ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot, /sbin/shutdown`

Answer (score 0):

Your line `gauri  ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot, /sbin/shutdown` should already be working to allow your user to reboot without `sudo`. Your issue is where you placed it.

If you look at the `sudoers` [man page](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html) for `#includedir`, you will see why:

> include /etc/sudoers.local
>
> When sudo reaches this line it will suspend processing of the current file (/etc/sudoers) and switch to
>   /etc/sudoers.local.

In your case, it is `/etc/sudoers.d`, but the same concept applies. You need to move the line `gauri  ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot, /sbin/shutdown` to above the `#includedir` section like so:

```
# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Allow user gauri to execute reboot without sudo
gauri  ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot, /sbin/shutdown

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```